# SharePoint 2010 help with Calculated Column formula

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I have a SharePoint 2010 Consensus column that weights the values of six potential risk raters. My column names are [risk1], [risk2], [risk3], [risk4], [risk5], [risk6].  Any risk rater who rates an item has a choice of Low, Med, or High.  Not all risk raters will rate every item and some items will have no rating initially.

My consensus logic is:

If all risk raters = Low then [Consensus] = Low;

If any risk rater (who rates) = Med and not High then [Consensus] = Med;

If any risk rater = High then [Consensus] = High

I can't get the formula right, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Thanks Paulster.  I can only get one piece at a time working

Comment: say =IF(AND([Risk1]="Low",[Risk2]="Low",[Risk3]="Low",[Risk4]="Low",[Risk5]="Low",[Risk6]="Low"),"Low","Med")

Comment: I tried addng a COUNTA condition to the above so that null values would not be evaluated but I am getting an illegal error.

Comment: I also tried several combinations of the following just to see if I could combine two if statements =IF(AND([Risk1]="Low",[Risk2]="Low",[Risk3]="Low",[Risk4]="Low",[Risk5]="Low",[Risk6]="Low"), "Low", "Med"),IF(OR([Risk1]="High",[Risk2]="High",[Risk3]="High",[Risk4]="High",[Risk5]="High",[Risk6]="High"), "High", "Med")   Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with:

```
 =IF(OR([Risk1]="High",[Risk2]="High",[Risk3]="High",[Risk4]="High",[Risk5]="High",[Risk6]="High"),"High",IF(OR([Risk1]="Med",[Risk2]="Med",[Risk3]="Med",[Risk4]="Med",[Risk5]="Med",[Risk6]="Med"),"Med","Low"))
```

Hope it helps someone else!